# How do cd, cd-absolute, and default-directory compare in GNU emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

How should I think about elisp functions `cd` and `cd-absolute` and the elisp variable `default-directory` when I'm customizing Emacs? My experience leads me to believe that `cd-absolute` changes the directory for the emacs process itself (a global setting across buffers where `default-directory` isn't set locally), while `cd` and `default-directory` are local to the buffer. The built-in help isn't sufficient to make me comfortable in my understanding, though, and I am seeing behavior that leads me to suspect `cd-absolute` is overriding `default-directory` in buffers I'm visiting.

*End-edit*

If I had received no answer here, I would have had to do my own research on the [help-gnu-emacs](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/help-gnu-emacs) list and, only as a last resort, I would have had to read the source code.

Comment: I'm not sure how to clarify the question yet, but I have another data point. I'm using a version of Joe Keane's background.el. It sets `default-direcgtory`. I'm still studying this.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the spelling, Richard. I intended to spell read r-e-e-d, but I have since softened my position. https://www.quora.com/profile/Tim-Chambers/Posts/reed-means-read-and-red-means-read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how `default-directory` works. Setting `default-directory` in your `.emacs` will have no effect on most buffers. The local value of `default-directory` for a buffer that is visiting a file is automatically set to the directory where the visited file is stored. This will over-ride any previously set value of `default-directory`.

If you change the current directory of a buffer via `cd` (or `cd-absolute`), this will set `default-directory` only for that buffer. If you then open a new file, `default-directory` for the new buffer gets set to the directory of the new file.

If you open a new buffer that is not visiting file, then the `default-directory` value of this new buffer will be the same as the value for the previous buffer. This is the only case where the result of `cd` will apply to a buffer other than the one it is called from.

`cd-absolute` is not intended for interactive use. As far as I can tell, it's a convenience function that differs from `cd` only in that the path is treated as an **absolute**, rather than **relative**, path.

Given all this, what are you trying to do?

Comment: There's also the case when `default-directory` is set for the buffer, which acts as a process input / output, which will depend on how you started the process, and is actually a bit awkward in the way it behaves. You can later change default directory in that buffer, but that won't affect the process it is associated with.

Comment: Tyler, I'm not worried about my `.emacs` file. One example of a custom function I'm writing is one that diffs the file in the current buffer against what I've edited. I want it to work with tramp. I'm still trying things.

Comment: I don't think default-directory will be useful in that case. buffer-filename and filename-directory, combined with cd, are likely what you're after.

Comment: Tyler's answer is thorough. It took me a couple weeks to track down the cause of the behavior that was troubling me. It turns out `compilation-start` mucks with `default-directory`. I was using `compilation-start` in a custom function I wrote and didn't know about that side-effect.